# Unwind known stack and instruction pointer with GDB

Tags: gdb, coredump, postmortem-debugging

I have a core dump on Linux x64. At some point SIGSEGV happened and unfortunately application handled this signal (but still failed in the end). So core dump doesn't directly contain frames of original SIGSEGV.

I was able to determine SP and IP (and other registers as well) of a failed instruction. Basically I have full ucontext structure.

Is there a way with GDB/LLDB instead of showing stacks on threads just unwind the backtrace from known SP/IP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way with GDB/LLDB instead of showing stacks on threads just unwind the backtrace from known SP/IP ?

The `RSP` and `RIP` are necessary, but *not sufficient*: you also need to know the *contents* of stack at the point of crash.

It sounds from your description that your signal handler attempted to recover from from this crash (perhaps by `siglongjmp`ing out), in which case the stack was unwound and its contents is probably gone.

It that is not the case, you may be able to unwind the stack by hand, but (as far as I know) GDB doesn't have any support for doing this. You'll have to examine unwind descriptors (`readelf -wf a.out`) and perform the necessary register restore operations by hand.

If your binary was built with frame pointers (this is not the default on `x86_64` in optimized builds), this is much easier: you'll only need to restore `RBP` and then follow frame pointer chain.

Comment: Yes, of course. Application under discussion is .NET Core. I don't really understand why they did all that magic with signal handlers while it should be ok to just crash on SIGSEGV. Anyway seems now I need to reproduce it live.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem I believe last week.  I had a crash where I didn't have the main executable or supporting libraries so gdb wasn't able to show a backtrace of the library I needed to debug.  I ended up fixing it by modifying the core file using magic_elf so that RSP and RIP in that thread were set to the registers reported by the segfault handler.

I wrote up a small tutorial on how this can be done:

http://www.mikekohn.net/software/core_file_analysis.php